# Google contact api returns Invalid XML Document error and Not saving to my contacts

Tags: ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-4, google-contacts-api

I'm using HTTP POST to create a new contact, but the contacts are saving in 'Other Contacts'.

Request body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry>
  <category scheme="https://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="https://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact" />
  <title>test Sun 6:00pm Ashwin P</title>
  <gd:name>
      <gd:fullName>test Sun 6:00pm Ashwin P</gd:fullName>
  </gd:name>
  <gd:phoneNumber label="Father">+6589822222</gd:phoneNumber>
  <gContact:groupMembershipInfo deleted="false" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/demo@gmail.com/base/6" />
</entry>
```

Another Request Body:

```
<atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
  <atom:category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"/>
  <gd:name>
    <gd:givenName>test Sun  6:00pm Ashwin P</gd:givenName>
    <gd:familyName>test Sun  6:00pm Ashwin P</gd:familyName>
    <gd:fullName>test Sun  6:00pm Ashwin P</gd:fullName>
  </gd:name>
  <atom:content type="text">Notes</atom:content>
  <gd:email rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work" primary="true" address="demo@gmail.com" displayName="test Sun  6:00pm Ashwin P"/> 
  <gd:email rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home" address="demo@gmail.com"/>
  <gd:phoneNumber rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home" primary="true">+6589822222</gd:phoneNumber> 
  <gContact:groupMembershipInfo deleted="false" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/paresh.tps@gmail.com/base/6"/>
</atom:entry>
```

The only solution that I found to insert the contact in 'My Contacts' has been to add this tag to XML request:

```
<gContact:groupMembershipInfo href='http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/demo@gmail.com/base/6'/>
```

Error:

```
REXML::ParseException
The document "<?xml version='1.0'?>\n" does not have a valid root
```

Response error

```
response.read_body
"Invalid XML Document."
```

Thanks

Comment: can you show us the complete body of the request?

Comment: Are you sure `\n` is an actual linebreak and not an escaped `\n`?

Comment: Yes, It's stop working from last 20 days.

Comment: @TamerShlash I added another request body. 
If I remove <gContact:groupMembershipInfo> then it's working but I want to add contacts under 'My Contact' System group.

Answer (score 0):

Just added the namespaces and it seems good

Here, need to replace

`<entry>`

with

`<entry
 xmlns:gd = "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/"
 xmlns:gContact = "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">`